# How to bulk insert into a Presto DB using Python

Tags: python, sql, insert, presto, bulkinsert

In my environment, I have to handle a lot of different data saved in Excel and CSV files. My python script reads all these Excel and CSV files, extracts the relevant data into a dataframe, and does some transformation.

The final step is to load the data into a Presto DB. The current code simply loops over the data and inserts every 500 records of the presto DB using an insert statement. This method seems to be complicated and slow. I tried it for every single record but the performance is of course unacceptable slow.

Is there any elegant method to bulk insert records from external data sources (Excel, CSV, ...) to a Presto database using python (and maybe an elegant insert statement)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the pyhive library in Python to bulk insert data into a Presto database. Here's how you can do it:

1. Install pyhive:

   ```
   pip install pyhive
   ```
2. Import the necessary libraries:

   ```
   from pyhive import presto
   import pandas as pd
   ```
3. Connect to your Presto database:

   ```
   conn = presto.connect(
     host='your_presto_host',
     port=your_presto_port,
     username='your_username',
     catalog='your_catalog',
     schema='your_schema'
   )
   ```

   Make sure to replace the placeholders (`your_presto_host`,
   `your_presto_port`, `your_username`, `your_catalog`, and `your_schema`)
   with the actual values for your Presto database.
4. Load your data into a pandas DataFrame. For example, if you have a CSV file named data.csv, you can load it into a DataFrame using the read_csv function:

   ```
     df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
   ```
5. Convert the DataFrame to a list of tuples, where each tuple represents a row in the database table:

   ```
     data = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
   ```
6. Create a SQL statement that inserts the data into the database table. The statement should have placeholders (%s) for the values to be inserted:

   ```
   sql = 'INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (%s, %s, %s, ...)'
   ```

Make sure to replace your_table with the actual name of the table in your
Presto database, and ... with the actual column names.

7. Use the executemany function to execute the SQL statement with the data:

```
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  cursor.executemany(sql, data)
  conn.commit()
```

The `executemany` function executes the SQL statement for each tuple in
the `data` list. The `commit` function commits the changes to the
database.

Using this method, you can insert a large amount of data into your Presto database efficiently and elegantly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That works. Is there any way to include conditions into each of the values such as "CASE WHEN val1=val2 THEN 'abc' else 'xyz' end" or something similar?

Comment: This is elegant, but folks should understand this is still equivalent to inserting a single row at a time. Depending on the width of your dataset, you'll start to see performance degradation ~100k rows and up. A few 100k may take ~5 min for a write to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced enough with Trino (Presto), but faced this problem. In case of partitioned table stored in parquets, [executemany()](https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client) and [to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) methods don't work because rows inserted separately, thus rewriting matching partition.

One way is to write rows into a temporary table ([memory tables](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/memory.html) for example) and then insert data into the destination table. In this case Trino properly writes entire partition.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

# connect to Trino
engine = create_engine("<trino_master_url>/mem")

df = pd.DataFrame(data_to_insert)
# write data into a temporary table
df.to_sql('my_table_tmp', engine, schema="default", index=False, if_exists='replace')

# load data into destination table
engine.execute("insert into my_catalog.default.my_table select * from mem.default.my_table_tmp")

# drop the temporary table
engine.execute("drop table if exists mem.default.my_table_tmp")
```

Another solution is to connect Trino directly to [CSV](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/object-storage-file-formats.html#parquet-format-configuration-properties) files stored in [S3](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive-s3.html) bucket and load data using SQL `INSERT INTO... SELECT...` statements

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just curious, have you actually tried the memory table setup option? I'm curious if that really would be faster.